# Show only right side of --side-by-side diff

Tags: command-line, text-processing, diff

I don't seem to find a way around this. Is there a one-liner to get only the right side of a `diff --side-by-side` output?

For example:

For this: `diff --side-by-side file1 file2` I get either of this two types of results:

```
  2 Africa                            |   3 Africa
  3 America                               3 America    
  3 Asia                                  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica                            4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania                               4 Oceania
  7 Europe                                7 Europe
```

or

```
  3 Africa                                3 Africa
  3 America                               3 America
  3 Asia                              <
  4 Antarctica                            4 Antarctica
                                      >   4 Asia
  4 Oceania                               4 Oceania
  8 Europe                                8 Europe
```

**How can I turn those into this:**

```
| 3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
```

**And this respectively:**

```
  3 Africa
  3 America
  4 Antarctica
> 4 Asia
  4 Oceania
  8 Europe
```

Note that I edited the original output of `diff` so that it appears justified in this question. They appear aligned (column-wise) in the terminal but I had to adjust them a little bit here so they appear exactly as they appear in the terminal (columns neatly aligned), but you can replicate the output creating this input files:

File1 version 1

```
  2 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
```

File2 version 1

```
  3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
```

File1 version 2

```
  3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  8 Europe
```

File2 version 2

```
  3 Africa
  3 America
  4 Antarctica
  4 Asia
  4 Oceania
  8 Europe
```

Comment: Is there really trailing whitespace after `3 America` in File2 version 2? is `7 Europe` meant to be `8 Europe` (same file)?

Comment: @steeldriver You are right. I corrected both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you seem to want is not a side-by-side diff at all - but rather one in which you customize the format to exclude lines from either the old or the new file completely. For example, given

```
$ cat file1v1
  2 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
$ cat file2v1
  3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
```

Then

```
$ diff --new-line-format='| %L' --unchanged-line-format='  %L' --old-line-format= file1v1 file2v1
|   3 Africa
    3 America
    3 Asia
    4 Antarctica
    4 Oceania
    7 Europe
```

while given

```
$ cat file1v2
  3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  8 Europe

$ cat file2v2
  3 Africa
  3 America
  4 Antarctica
  4 Asia
  4 Oceania
  8 Europe
```

then

```
$ diff --new-line-format='> %L' --unchanged-line-format='  %L' --old-line-format= file1v2 file2v2
    3 Africa
    3 America
    4 Antarctica
>   4 Asia
    4 Oceania
    8 Europe
```

Comment: +1 For the great answer. Problem is I don't know before hand whether the comparison will yield `|`s , `>`, or boths. Sample text files are merely illustrative.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the RIGHT column, though it ends up on the left. Also, it's a very ugly solution and I'm sure some smarter folks will do better. But here is is anyway:

```
$ diff --side-by-side file1 file2 | sed -r 's/[^\t]*\t*(.*)/\1/' | sed -r 's/^ *(\||>|<)\t /\1/'

| 3 Africa
  3 America
  3 Asia
  4 Antarctica
  4 Oceania
  7 Europe
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new
- `[^\t]*` anything but tabs, please
- `\t*` as many tabs as you like
- `(.*)` any number of any characters on the line, (saved) for later
- `\1` the pattern we saved
- `s/^ *(\||>|<)\t /\1/` get rid of the stuff around the `|` or `>` or `<` character on lines that differ to fix the alignment

Comment: +1 For the great answer. Problem is I don't know before hand whether the comparison will yield |s , >, or boths. Sample text files are merely illustrative.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova thanks :) I changed it to catch all of the characters, but I am not sure it does quite what you want